# How can I convert UTC to a DateTime?

Tags: java, datetime, date, utc

I have the following date:

```
2011-05-24T11:40:41Z
```

How can I convert this into a Joda DateTime?

**EDIT**:
Here is my code that does not compile:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"); 
                        Date date = df.parse(aMessage.getString("updated_at"));
                        org.joda.time.DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
```

Errors:

```
The method parse(String) is undefined for the type DateFormat   
Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleDateFormat to DateFormat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Joda's [user guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Input_and_Output):

> All printing and parsing is performed using a `DateTimeFormatter` object.

You should be able to just use the [ISODateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) factory directly in this instance:

```
String inputDateString = "2011-05-24T11:40:41Z";

DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
DateTime result = fmt.parseDateTime(inputDateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DatFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). It has a [parse()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lan) method you could use.

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    df.parse("2011-05-24T11:40:41Z");
    org.joda.time.DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
```

Comment: That doesn't compile. A SimpleDateFormat can't be assigned to df. And df.parse can't do a string.

Comment: why not? i am pasting my compiled code here:                public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        Date date = df.parse("2011-05-24T11:40:41Z");
        org.joda.time.DateTime dt = new DateTime(date);
    }

Comment: make sure that it is java.text.DateFormat